# Trying to display the dropdown option by fetching the values from the server

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an Angular reactive form which serves two functionalities

- Adding new values
- Updating existing values

I am able to achieve these functionalities and of course am storing the values in backend (MongoDB) and am using post and put method to achieve the mentioned functionalities.

The only issue am facing is am populating the dropdown options fetched from the server, So while adding the new value, It works perfectly fine but when I try to fetch the existing value I can see other input fields populated with proper values. But the dropdown list order remains constant and it's not changing to the value which was stored using post method.

**TS** - Sets the value to the fields

```
this.opportunityForm.get('type').setValue(this.opportunities.opportunity_Type);
```

**TS** - Get the Dropdown options from the server

```
/* Fetch Type */  
       this.http
       .get('http://localhost:3000/api/types')
       .pipe(
         map(responseData => {

           return responseData;
         })
       )
       .subscribe(posts => {
         // ...
         this.types = posts;
         console.log(posts);
       });
```

**Template Html**

```
<select placeholder = "Select a Type" formControlName="type" class="form-control" >
      <option *ngFor = "let opptype of types?.Types">{{ opptype.type }}</option>
</select>
```

Adding Image of the value which stored in DB.

Existing Value which got stored using POST

[image: 1]

Adding the image of how the form displays the value with constant order.

Dropdown options

[image: 2]

Comment: Yes, the expected value is coming

Comment: Did you console log the `this.opportunities.opportunity_Type` just before this line: `this.opportunityForm.get('type').setValue(this.opportunities.opportunity_Type);`